# MVC Test Controller ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I have some problems implementing Spring MVC Test with Spring Framework 3.2 (following http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework).

To summarize :

I use Maven 3.0.4.

I have multiple projects using Spring Framework. The relevant projects hierarchy is :

- common
- dao
- webservices (using common and dao)

In webservices, I have one Controller

```
package com.lalala;
...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WebServicesController {
    @Autowired private WebService webService;

    //some methods...
}
```

WebService class is declared as an interface and has an implementation.

Now, the test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("/testApplicationContext.xml")
public class WebServicesTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new WebServicesController()).build();
}

@Test
public void inexistentService() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("webservices/pong").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is(500)).andDo(print());
}
```

}

and the configuration file testApplicationContext.xml :

```
<beans ... >
    <import resource="classpath:spring-hibernate-test.xml"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lalala"/>
</beans>
```

When I try to launch the test in Eclipse, I have a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lalala.WebServicesController. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my configuration and my test?

(Beside that, the project works fine once deployed in tomcat and just to know if I was writing wrong Tests, I tried to launch already existing tests which work perfectly on jenkins. They don't work locally.)

Comment: Are you using Maven as well?

Comment: @AyubMalik yes I use Maven 3.0.4

Comment: @jchips12 Thanks for your advice but I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the deployed resources "libraries", the libraries that you are using in the build path should be deployed in your project.

Properties > Deployment Assembly > add libraries from build path

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear problem of classpath. Here is my approach to solve this:

- First find out the jar file on which problematic class file is present. If you don't know how to find which jar file a particular class you can see eclipse shortcuts to do that or you can simply do "Ctrl+T" in Eclipse and type the name of class, It will list all the jar in the order they appear in eclipse classpath.
- Check whether your classpath contains that jar, if your classpath doesn't contain the jar then just add that class in your classpath.
- If it’s present in your classpath then there is high chance that your classpath is getting overridden or application is using classpath specified in jar file or start-up script and to fix that you need to find the exact classpath used by your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a classpath issue, or a simple build issue. I don't think it is related to Spring MVC specifically. Especially since you are using Maven.

If **not** using Eclipse Maven plugin, run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

on command line, in your project folder

Then check the following in Eclipse.

- 'Project | Build' automatically is checked
- WebServicesController is in src/main/java branch (not src/test/java)
- src/main/java is project is
  in Java Build Path. Right click on the project in Eclipse and check
  the settings.

Once checked, do a 'Project | Clean' in Eclipse

Comment: I followed your instructions but my problem is still the same.

Comment: what is the output if you run 'mvn test' on the command line?

Comment: My comment was before your edit. I used mvn eclipse:eclipse and my project is totally broken now and the problem has changed : Failed to load ApplicationContext. I will rollback I think

Comment: sorry you can use mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse to generate a working project. I use this at work